# How to only show the file/directory column in a Dired buffer

Tags: dired

When visiting a directory: In the view that comes up, I want the file/directory names to be in the left-most column.   How can I do that?

Comment: This is not entirely clear: by default find-file will prompt you to choose a file but there is no view with columns. Are you perhaps asking about the directory listing you get after using `C-x C-f` to open a directory? That would be a question about `dired`.

Comment: you are correct, i am asking about the directory listing that comes up

Comment: OK, I've revised the question and tags a bit to make that clear. I've offered my own answer but perhaps others will have some suggestions on getting the display you want.

Comment: Please make clear in the question that you do not care whether any other columns are shown, besides the file name. There is a big difference between showing only file names and rearranging the column order. Emacs provides the first but not the second.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming this question is about `dired` (the Emacs directory editor mode), there is no simple built-in way to rearrange the columns. Dired is presenting the output of an `ls` command so you can customize `dired-listing-switches` if there are ls output options that you prefer.

You can also switch to a very simple dired view by using the key <kbd>(</kbd> in a dired buffer -- this is bound by default to the command `dired-hide-details-mode`, which will drop all the columns and just show the file names.

Beyond that I believe you would need to look for an optional package or write some elisp yourself to build a custom directory view.

You can learn more about Dired in the Emacs manual ([online](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html), or use <kbd>C-h i</kbd> to browse the manuals in Emacs itself.)